# Rank and determinant of a tensor product of matrices

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-rank, kronecker-product

> If $A\in M_{n\times n}(F)$ and $B\in M_{m\times m}(F)$, show that $\mathrm{rk}(A\otimes B) = \mathrm{rk}(A)\mathrm{rk}(B)$ and $\det(A\otimes B)=\det(A)^m\det(B)^n$.

Let $p:=rk(A)$ and $q:=rk(B)$, then in $A\otimes B$ there can only be $p$ columns of matrix B and in each column of those matrices there are $q$ columns, which gives the rank of $A\otimes B$ is $rk(A)rk(B)$, is this argument well? For the second part I consider that the best way to do it is with the determinant as summation but I do not remember very well how it is expressed, could someone please tell me? Would it be better to calculate det$(A\otimes B)$ by which column or row? Thank you!

Comment: It might help to consider elementary row operations.

Comment: @i707107 as which?

Comment: Using the Jordan normal form should resolve all questions

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Suppose that $PAP^{-1}$ is upper triangular, as is $QBQ^{-1}$.  Then 
$$
(P \otimes Q)(A \otimes B)(P \otimes Q)^{-1} = 
(PAP^{-1}) \otimes (QBQ^{-1})
$$
is a tensor product of upper-triangular matrices.  Note that this product is itself upper-triangular.